# Read large csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

Would you like to tell how to read 3 gb csv file, because when I try to read with read.csv I stumble upon on this error “Error: cannot allocate vector of size 250.0 Mb”. My machine is i5 4 gb ram Win 7 32 bit. Moreover, I try to use ff package to open it and again I face error that I should use 64 bit version of R to be able to read csv file as well as I need more ram to read it. Should I take into account to use scan function. I try to use scan function but I want to use skip = 4 and nlines = 2 in my code and when I try to use it I read only first row of my data.

Comment: Packages [ff](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html) or [bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html) might be of interest. However, RAM is cheap and a 64bit system is also affordable. If you need to work with data of this size regularly, you should take that option.

Comment: I try to use scan to read the file, but again I face the issue "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 250.0 Mb". What to do?

Answer (score 3):

R operates completely in memory (RAM), so once it runs out of available space, the `read.csv` operation will fail hard.  To get around this, you can try increasing the amount of available memory:

```
memory.limit(size=8097)   # allocate 8097 MB = 8 GB for R to use
```

You will need the 64 bit version of R to take advantage of this.  And you may have to increase the memory beyond 8 GB to get your operation to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to complete an analysis that requires too much *random access memory* with your current method of *memory management*, then I recommend adjusting your analysis to utilize *virtual memory* so long as you have *hard disk* space to spare.

Comment: Virtual memory is slow, in particular if you don't use an SSD.